# how to zip sequentially by any given number n in python?

Tags: python, zip

If I do

```
result = list(zip(a[0:],a[1:],a[2:]))
```

from list

```
a = [1, 3, -1, -3, 5, 3, 6, 7]
```

, then result should be

```
result =  [(1, 3, -1), (3, -1, -3), (-1, -3, 5), (-3, 5, 3), (5, 3, 6), (3, 6, 7)]
```

But I need to zip sequentially not fixed number but by any given number n in function such as

```
def sequen_zip(lst, n):
    return list(zip(lst[0:],....,lst[n-1]))
```

Therefore, I want to zip by any sequential zip by n group in one line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can slice using `range` to generate the start indices in a generator epxression:

```
def sequen_zip(lst, n):
    return list(zip(*(lst[i:] for i in range(n))))
```

---

*Demo*:

```
>>> sequen_zip(a, 1)
[(1,), (3,), (-1,), (-3,), (5,), (3,), (6,), (7,)]
>>> sequen_zip(a, 2)
[(1, 3), (3, -1), (-1, -3), (-3, 5), (5, 3), (3, 6), (6, 7)]
>>> sequen_zip(a, 3)
[(1, 3, -1), (3, -1, -3), (-1, -3, 5), (-3, 5, 3), (5, 3, 6), (3, 6, 7)]
```

Comment: Thank you! I forget to parenthesize *( )  on lst[i:] for i in range(n). I did just  lst[i:] for i in range(n)...

Answer (score 0):

Use a generator to iterate through the desired range of values. You do not need the `list` call in the loop as `zip` already returns a `list` object.

```
def sequen_zip(lst, n):
    return zip(*(lst[i:] for i in range(n)))

a = [1, 3, -1, -3, 5, 3, 6, 7]
print(sequen_zip(a, 3))
# [(1, 3, -1), (3, -1, -3), (-1, -3, 5), (-3, 5, 3), (5, 3, 6), (3, 6, 7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, just like with strings, get a part of a array using [start:end]. The following code should word for any length.

```
a = [1, 3, -1, -3, 5, 3, 6, 7]
res = []
n = 3
while len(a) >= n:
    res.append(tuple(a[0:n]))
    a.pop(0)

print(res)
```

The result being

```
[(1, 3, -1), (3, -1, -3), (-1, -3, 5), (-3, 5, 3), (5, 3, 6), (3, 6, 7)]
```

This should work for any length n for any array.